# Hiding a type inside a class and use that internally

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a shared library (.so) and I want to hide the internal types I'm using without success. I'm using SFML to draw but I want to provide my own interface not the SFML one.

If I do this:

```
class Texture: public sf::Texture {
};
```

Then I can use the interface from sf::Texture. But I want different return types from the functions that sf::Texture has (Example: getSize() etc..)
So It's not a solution :(.

If I do this:

```
class Texture {
public:
    vec2 get_size() const{ return vec2(m_t.getSize()); }
private:
    sf::Texture m_t;
};
```

That looks better but I have another problem.. to use that sf::Texture with for example a sf::Sprite I need access to that internal type (sf::Texture) then I need to add a method like this:

```
sf::Texture& get_internal_texture() {return m_t;}
```

This is bad because I don't want that the user of the library can access to that internal variable...

How will you handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`friend` is your friend here.

```
class Texture {
friend class ClassThatWantsToUseTextureVariable;
public:
    vec2 get_size() const{ return vec2(m_t.getSize()); }
private:
    sf::Texture m_t;
};
```

or better yet just declare as friend the method that will be using the variable

```
friend int ClassThatWantsToUseTextureVariable::methodThatWantsToUseTextureVariable();
```

Comment: Well that's a solution :). Thank you!